# Python/Django 'OperationalError' in admin Django Rest Framework (DRF)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I keep getting the Operational error below in my Django admin when I try to update a models table.
I'm trying to add a new field to the polls table.
What could be the problem?
Thanks in advance!

```
OperationalError at /admin/vote/poll/add/

no such table: main.auth_user__old

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:            http://localhost:8000/admin/vote/poll/add/
Django Version:     2.0.3
Exception Type:     OperationalError
Exception Value:    no such table: main.auth_user__old
Exception Location:     D:\Studio\Python\REST\elections\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 303
Python Executable:  D:\Studio\Python\REST\elections\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     3.9.0
Python Path:
```

The polls model: models.py

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

The urls.py code:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("polls/", PollList.as_view(), name="polls_list"),
    path("polls/<int:pk>/", PollDetail.as_view(), name="polls_detail"),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any specific reason you are using Django v2 instead of v3.

You could do a couple of things to resolve this:

- Upgrade Django version to 2.2 or above.
- Downgrade SQLite version if you are using one.

After that you can delete the old database, and run you migrations again:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```